# Navigate to UIViewController from SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, swiftui

My initial view is built using SwiftUI.

I'd like to transition to a UIViewController from this & call a method that may alter the design, an example is hiding an IBOutlet.

Here's what I am doing currently:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct DetailViewControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = DetailViewController

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DetailViewControllerWrapper>) -> DetailViewControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType {

        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let detailViewController: DetailViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailViewController") as! DetailViewController
        detailViewController.someMethod()
        return detailViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: DetailViewControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DetailViewControllerWrapper>) {
        //
    }
}
```

This is pushing to my DetailViewController but I'm getting a `Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` error.

Any advice on navigating from SwiftUI to UIKit / UIViewController?

Comment: I'm guessing that `detailViewController.someMethod()` uses an `IBOutlet` property? And the crash breakpoint is pointing to that property usage? I think the outlet is simply not set yet directly after instantiating the view controller.

Comment: If you see view of `DetailViewController` and then crash, then it is in implementation of `DetailViewController`, not in provided code.

Comment: I've made some progress but one thing I have encountered is my status bar is initially hidden, but when navigating from my SwiftUI View to my UIIVewController it becomes unhidden, even though prefersStatusBarHidden is being called. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Part of working with `UIViewRepresentable` is calling a required func called `makeCoordinator()` as cited [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable/3278042-coordinator) in the docs. Apple also has a tutorial on how to interface with UIKit which you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit). Another tutorial from Paul Hudson [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/using-coordinators-to-manage-swiftui-view-controllers) might also be useful to you. I used the coordinator pattern from it to provide an `UIImagePickerController` in a SwiftUI app I'm working on. That code is below. You'll notice the nested class which provides the functionality I need for the `UIImagePickerController`, in your case I believe you just need to call the DetailViewController. I hope this helps. -Dan

```
import SwiftUI

class PhotosData: NSObject, Codable {
    var image: String?

    init(image: String) {
        self.image = image
      }
    }

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var image: UIImage?

class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    let parent: ImagePicker

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            parent.image = uiImage
        }
        parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }

    init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
        self.parent = parent
        }
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) { 
    /*Required. Not used*/ 
        }

}
```

Comment: I set up my coordinator but I'm still getting the same message on my outlet. Though, I don't have context.coordinator set. I'm not entirely sure how to do to that just on a ViewController since I'm not using an ImagePicker or anything like that.

Comment: Scratch that above. I'm able to navigate now and have the right method called. Couple things I'm seeing though, my status bar which starts as hidden becomes visible when the navigation is complete. Also, the best way to navigate back to the SwiftUI View? Using popToViewController works but then I'm stuck at the SwiftUI and can't go back.

Comment: If the status bar is becoming visible when you're in the SwiftUI view try adding the modifier `.statusBar(hidden: true)` to the View. I'm not certain on the second part of your question unfortunately. Are you able to post of of the navigation code?

Comment: Hey @LukeIrvin how you made that happen?